# Compiling RIDE contracts with Python or JS

Tags: wavesplatform, ride

Is it possible to compile RIDE contracts locally with Python or JS? I've only found a Java-based compiler, which is less than ideal for a browser app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS library [Waves-Transactions](https://github.com/wavesplatform/waves-transactions) to create transactions such as Set script, Set asset script or InvokeScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JS compiler for RIDE, you can find it here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@waves/ride-js